# XMLHttpRequest bad response with firefox

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, request, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem when i try to get data from my Server by `XMLHttpRequest` with Firefox (it works well on Google Chrome)

The value of `XMLHttpRequest.response` is twice the normal value

Let me show you, when i try with Chrome, the response is :

```
"[{"field1": value1, "field2": value2}]"
```

This is perfect

But with Firefox, response is :

```
"[{"field1": value1, "field2": value2}][{"field1": value1, "field2": value2}]"
```

It's exactly the same data, and without a ',' between them. So when i try to do an `JSON.parse(response)`, it fail.

This is how i do my XMLHttpRequest :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/api/Gifts/full');
xhr.onload = onLoad;
xhr.send(null)

function onLoad() {
  // We can see here the problem here
  console.log('this response = ', this.response);
}
```

Why firefox send me the value twice ?

EDIT :

I add `xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');` and it seems working but only for latest version of mozilla (54.0.1). It's really weird

Comment: Seems like an issue with the server, not the browser.

Comment: I am not sure if the behavior of just slapping an `onload` onto an `XMLHttpRequest` object is actually specified anywhere ... you should rather handle this the way it was designed, using `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: I checked data return by my server and they are good :/

Comment: Actually, when i write the data i return in the server, they are correct, but the response in the console of the browser of the server is not good. How can this happen ?

@CBroe after research, onreadystatechange and onload seems to be same, but people recommand using onload.

Comment: Try setting the event handler before the `open` call. MDN says somewhere that if you don’t do that, progress events won’t fire correctly - possible this has an effect on load as well, I suppose.

Comment: MDN say that if you do an addEventListener. But i tried, i set the event handler before the `open` , i also tried to changed it into `xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);` but it still doesn't work..

Comment: I just have saw that the return code is 304 which means that data is cached. Is it possible that firefox takes this data and takes data from server too, so this explain i have twice the same data ?